# IDA pro CTRL and + keypad whenever debugging

Tags: ida, idapython

How can I remove the CTRL and + keypad whenever I am debugging PE file in IDA?
All of the disassembled codes are wrapped up whenever I debug a PE file and I see the message CTRL and + keypad to collapse the code. How can I remove that mode so I have all the code collapsed down while debugging in the first place?

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand the question. But when debugging, you generally need all code expanded, because IDA won't be able to show the current instruction otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *Browser* tab of IDA's *Options* window, check *Unhide collapsed items automatically when jumping to them*:

[image: IDA Options]

From IDA's help file:

> If this option is set on, IDA will automatically uncollapse hidden
>   functions if the user decides to jump to them. As soon as the user
>   quits the function by pressing Esc, the function is automatically
>   collapsed again.

Comment: How to open the option window ?